# Open a PDF with Actionview C#

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin

So im working with Xamarin in Visual Studio for the first time and i want to open a PDF file which is stored in the apk. I have researched now for about an hour but nothing helped me out. My problem is that don't know where the pdf in the project folder should be stored and how to get the path of the folder or the file, to open it with a ActionView

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/

Comment: Yeah i already know how to output a Text, but still  i dont know how to open a pdf

Comment: Copy the PDF Asset out of your app package to a temp file (open it as a Stream and redirect that input stream to a FileStream to save it.. Then you can open that file externally. Otherwise setup a file provider and then you can stream a FileDescriptor to a temp file and open that.